# How to use java to connect hadoop 2.2.0 server

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I just created a hadoop server with version 2.2.0 on centos 6. The server is running fine.

Now I am trying to use eclipse to upload a file to the server. I can't connect it in the java. I am using eclipse Indingo on Mac.

I am using the eclipse-plugin for hadoop. But looks like it is for hadoop 1.x. There is no tutorial for how to create the plugin for 2.x.

Can anyone give me a tutorial about how to connect the hadoop server?

Answer (score 0):

> The Hadoop Development Tools (HDT) is a set of plugins for the Eclipse
>   IDE for developing against the Hadoop platform.
>
> Currently we are in the process of porting the existing MapReduce
>   tools from the Apache Hadoop project to allow working with multiple
>   versions of Hadoop from within one IDE.
>
> Come get involved as we move towards our first release!
>
> This project is currently a member of the Apache Incubator, so check
>   back for updates, or come join us dev@hdt.incubator.apache.org.

--- [Apache Hadoop Development Tools](http://hdt.incubator.apache.org/)